# days away from nearest holiday - python jupyter notebook - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'daysAway' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to python and jupyter notebook and I am doing an exercise that asks to give the number of days away from a number of given holidays given dates stored in a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Input' : ['next_holiday(2019,1,31)',
            'next_holiday(2019,13,3)',
            'next_holiday(2040,8,2)',
            'next_holiday(2022,2,29)',
            'next_holiday(2021,9,19)',
            'next_holiday(2020,2,29)',
            'next_holiday(2008,12,25)',
            'next_holiday(2022,12,28)']
})
```

I have been successfully able to isolate the date and have made a valid date checker although I have been encountering some problems in the code that gets the number of days away from the holiday

```
import numpy as np
import calendar
from datetime import date

def next_holiday(x):
    #isolating date
    dates = x.strip("next_holiday()")
    year = int(dates.split(',')[0])
    month = int(dates.split(',')[1])
    day = int(dates.split(',')[2])

    validD = False
    validM = False
    output1 = ""
    output2 = ""

    #day and month validity
    if month < 13 and month > 0:
        validM = True
        if month==1 or month==3 or month ==5 or month==7 or month==8 or month==10 or month==12:
        #day validity for months with 31 days
        if day < 32 and day > 0:
            validD = True 
    elif month==4 or month==6 or month==9 or month==11:
        #day validity for months with 30 days
        if day < 31 and day > 0:
            validD = True
    elif month==2:
        #day validity for feb with 29 days in consideration of leap year
        if calendar.isleap(year) == True:
            if day < 30 and day > 0:
                validD = True
        else:
            if day < 29 and day > 0:
                validD = True      
    
    #holiday list
    holidates = [ ["New Year's day",1,1],  #holiday [0][0] Jan 1
            ["Family Day",2,17],     #holiday [1][0] Feb 17
            ["Good Friday",4,10],    #holiday [2][0] Apr 10
            ["Victoria Day",5,18],   #holiday [3][0] May 18
            ["Canada Day",7,1],      #holiday [4][0] Jul 1
            ["Civic Holiday",8,3],   #holiday [5][0] Aug 3
            ["Labor Day",9,7],       #holiday [6][0] Sep 7
            ["Labor DAy",10,12],     #holiday [7][0] Oct 12
            ["Christmas Day",12,25], #holiday [8][0] Dec 25
            ["Boxing Day",12,26] ]   #holiday [9][0] Dec 26

    if validD == True and validM == True:
        count = 0 
        daysAway = []
        while count < 10:
            def numOfDays(date1, date2):
                return (date2-date1).days

            date1 = date(year, month, day)
            if month == 12 and day > 26:
                date2 = date(year+1, holidates[count][1], holidates[count][2])
            else:
                date2 = date(year, holidates[count][1], holidates[count][2])
        
            daysAway = np.array(list(numOfDays(date1, date2)))
            count = count + 1
    
        output2 = min(daysAway)
        output1 = holidates[daysAway.index(output2)][0]
        
    elif (validD == False and validM == False) or validM == False:
        output1 = "'invalid month'"
        output2 = "-1"
    else:
        output1 = "'invalid day'"
        output2 = "-1"

    finalOutput = '[' + output1 +',' + output2 + ']'
    return finalOutput
                
df['Output'] = df['Input'].apply(next_holiday)
```

update: it is solved now I changed the following:

```
daysAway = []
output2 = min(daysAway)
output1 = holidates[daysAway.index(output2)][0]
daysAway = np.array(list(numOfDays(date1, date2)))
```

to:

```
daysAwaylist = []
daysAway = min([i for i in daysAwaylist if i > 0])
output2 = str(daysAway)
output1 = holidates[daysAwaylist.index(min([i for i in daysAwaylist if i > 0]))][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

'days_away' has its value set inside of a conditional statement block (`if validD == True and validM == True`). If this condition isn't true, the 'days_away' variable will be used before it is assigned a value, causing the error you're getting. What should the value of 'days_away' be if either `validD` or `validM` aren't True?

Comment: if validD or validM wasn't true it shouldn't need 'daysAway' variable in the first place since  'daysAway' is only needed if validD and validM is true. if it is false, it should skip the entire code segment that involves daysAway, right?

Comment: You have the line `output2 = min(daysAway)` outside of that case, so the program is still trying to use the daysAway variable when either validD or validM is not true. I'd indent this line and the next to be in the if block

Comment: oh sorry, it's not like that on my code just missed it when pasting it on here will change it thank you

Comment: You have another probelm with your while loop condition. count is set to 0, and then the condition of the while loop will never be satisfied (count > 10 can't be true if count = 0). Because the while loop condition isn't met, the loop block is never entered, and daysAway never gets set. Once you fix this, make sure you increment the 'count' variable somewhere in the loop or else you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed that now but I have a new problem appearing that says "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" on the line of output 2 = min(daysAway)

Comment: Yes, min() expects something iterable, like an array. I'd make sure that daysAway is a list or something and not just an int, otherwise you'll get that error.

Comment: it still shows that same error even if I tried to define it as: daysAway = list()

Comment: Is that before or after `daysAway = numOfDays(date1, date2)`? Is `numOfDays(date1, date2)` returning an int or a list? It also might be worth marking this question as answered and writing a new question.

Comment: there i've changed it now to a list turned array but for some reason it says my syntax in count = count + 1 is incorrect

Comment: you're missing a closing parentheses on the line before.

Comment: oh, but now it still says 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What is daysAway supposed to be? What is numOfDays supposed to return? How are they meant to work together? If daysAway is meant to be a list of the results of `numOfDays` for each value of count, you need to be appending the results of the `numOfDays` function to it, which you aren't currently doing.

Comment: numOfDays return the number of days between the given date and a holiday and daysAway is supposed to store a collection of that based on different holidays and find the lowest to find the nearest holiday and the days towards it. How would you recommend I append it?

Comment: create a list before the while loop, append each result of numOfDayst within the while loop to it, then take the min of that outside the while loop.

Comment: i stated the changes i've made in the og post, thank you for all the help and the patience, it is very much appreciated